# PersistentTokenRepository : Remember-Me and AJAX

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I think there is a problem with the persistentTokenRepository and the detection of **"cookie theft attack"**, it detects false positive.

In fact sometimes I get this error :

```
Etat HTTP 500 - Invalid remember-me token (Series/token) mismatch. Implies previous cookie theft attack.
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.CookieTheftException: Invalid remember-me token (Series/token) mismatch. Implies previous cookie theft attack.
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.processAutoLoginCookie(PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.java:102)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.AbstractRememberMeServices.autoLogin(AbstractRememberMeServices.java:115)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:97)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

After some investigation, I have understand the problem ! my webapp use a lot of ajax request for the first load, so we can have several thread in same time that try to get the security token for the same session and because the first thread that accomplish the authentication of the session do a updatetoken  the others can't do that because the original token (that these thread hold) has been updated and the exception is launched.

The problem doesn't occurs each time because the RememberMeAuthenticationFilter check if the rememberMeAuth (doFilter) is set so the problem is more frequent with the use of asynchronous request.

Do you think there is a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Any updates on this? I have same problem, but even without ajax

Comment: also having this problem. very hard to reproduce so I'm not sure what to do. but people are complaining about getting errors.